# What are my options for moving an SSH certificate to a new server?

Tags: lets-encrypt

I have an ubuntu server running through Digital Ocean that has an SSH certificate that I got through LetsEncrypt.

I'm trying to switch to a cheaper service, and I need to move the cert to my new server. How can I do this?

It looks like I can revoke the certificate on my current DO server. Can I then make a new one on my new server without any problems?

Comment: This would be more appropriate on Server Fault, which deals with server administration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can move the SSL certs to your new server providing you will be using the same domain/s again. also If you create new ones and put them in place the the older ones will be revoked.

I'd cd into the letsencrypt/live directory first and backup  the existing ones up to though.

```
cp -R certs certs.bak
```

change the directory names to suit your own.